# Symfony2 - allow user to log in with their own Google account

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, google-api

What is the best way to allow user to log in with their own Google account in Symfony2?
I know how google API works. But how to implement a custom authentification provider ?

I already read this [documention](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) but i don't understand why I have to create a custom user class. I want to fetch user credentials with Google API, test if user email exists in my bdd and then log the user.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) - it supports authenication via lots of OAuth providers, including goodle.

A quick example config for google using this bundle would be :

```
hwi_oauth:
    resource_owners:
        any_name:
            type:                google
            client_id:           <client_id>
            client_secret:       <client_secret>
            scope:               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
```

Where `<client_id>` and `<client_secret>` are your details.

Comment: I test HWIOAuthBundle, i follow the steps and I have this error =>

You have requested a non-existent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.main"

Comment: @alex are you sure you added the new bundle to `appkernel.php` ?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution on here :
http://www.diegocaprioli.com/adding-hwioauthbundle-to-your-symfony2-project/